# Cannot load referenced assemblies for reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

My application generates diagrams from the code structure of .NET applications. `Assembly.LoadFile` works, but only if my application has been put in the same folder as the assembly that I'm loading (seems to be due to referenced assemblies); if its not in the same folder, I get a `ReflectionTypeLoadException` exception if the loaded assembly had dependencies not in the GAC.

I've tried using `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom` instead.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve += ResolveAssembly;
Assembly loadedAssembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(FileName);
```

With the following event:

```
Assembly ResolveAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args){
    return Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(args.Name);
}
```

But that `ResolveAssembly` only got called for `System`, `System.Windows.Forms`, and `System.Drawing`. It did not get called for `OpenTK.dll`, `OpenTK.GLControl.dll` and other referenced assemblies. And it too threw a `ReflectionTypeLoadException` when I called `loadedAssembly.GetTypes()`.

How can I get it to load the referenced assemblies, so that I don't have to enforce my application be put in the same folder as the assembly its inspecting?

**Update:**

When I call `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom`, I can use `GetReferencedAssemblies()` to observe the references from that assembly. When I examine `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyGetAssemblies()`, I notice only a single assembly was loaded (the one originally specified). In otherwords, the referenced assemblies are simply not being loaded (despite the `ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve` hook).

Comment: perhaps they are loaded in a separate app domain?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you could try would be handling the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event and resolving it yourself.

The second thing I might consider is spawning a second `AppDomain` with the bin / probe-path set as the target directory, and basically relocating the work inside of that `AppDomain`.

However, I would also put serious consideration into using a standalone loader, i.e. that isn't tied into the .NET runtime *at all*. In some similar work (inspecting assemblies that aren't really related to the app itself - just for information etc) I make a lot of use of IKVM.Reflection.dll, which allows you to create a separate `Universe` - it has the same basic API as regular reflection, but frankly it doesn't get as confused (plus it allows you to load assemblies for other target platforms, which is handy).

Comment: Tried both (#1 and #2), still no luck. Always either getting `BadImageFormatException`, `ReflectionTypeLoadException`, or a `FileNotFoundException`. Yet when my application is in the same folder, it works. So strange.

Comment: @Mr.Smith since I listed 3 options, which "both" have you tried?

Comment: @Mr.Smith `BadImageFormatException` is also thrown when you try to load an assembly that are not compiled for current framework. Did you check this ?

Comment: @Fabske My application is presently compiled for `v4.0` with `Any CPU`. The loaded assembly is `v2.0` with `x86`. This still needs to work though, and does work (with `Assembly.LoadFile`) if placed in same directory.